# How do I categorize my screen sizes?

Tags: android, nativescript

I have listed 2 of a screensize I want to adapt to (and counting):

my Lenovo A536: 480 x 854 pixels (~196 ppi pixel density)
and Samsung Galaxy S5: 1080 x 1920 pixels (~432 ppi pixel density)

and in [this page](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/supporting-multiple-screen-resolutions-in-your-nativescript-app) listed: 320dp, 480dp, 600dp, 720dp as "breakpoints" to trigger which xml, css to load... but I don't know how to categorize the screen sizes that I listed above (even when using the formula)...

Please help... Thanks...

Comment: read this to get  a better idea https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: copy/paste from the documentation: `minWH[dp value] instructs the system to load the particular layout file when the smaller dimension of the screen (width or height) is at least the value of dp. The minWH[dp value] qualifier does not depend on the device’s orientation.

The minW[dp value] and minH[dp value] are similar to minWH[dp value] but work on just one dimension and are orientation dependent.` - this is what you're looking for.

Comment: its not exactly you need to use 320dp, 480dp, 600dp, 720dp.. you can use 100dp, 150dp, 200dp and etc according to your need..

Comment: and this is one more reason you shouldn't use fixed sizes in the layouts.

Comment: Thanks... I'll study the link and come back if I still have questions... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target any screen size dpi. You can use the following screen size qualifiers:

- minWH<X> - The smaller dimension (width or height) should be at least
  X dp.
- minW<X> - Width should be at least X dp.
- minH<X> - Height should be at least X dp.

So, if you want to target 196 dpi, you define the page like this:

**your-page.minW196.xml** - Applied for a minimum width of 196 dp.

For more information visit nativescript docs [screen size qualifiers](http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#screen-size-qualifiers).

---

Here are the following list of most popular screen resolutions:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device                Screen size      dpi       Suggested ratio   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| iPhone 5 / iPod Touch 1136 × 640       326ppi    2                 |
| iPhone 4              960 × 640        326ppi    2                 |
| iPhone 4S             960 × 640        326ppi    2                 |
| iPad (3rd gen)        2048 × 1536      264ppi    2                 |
| MacBook Retina        2880 x 1800      220ppi    2                 |
| Xperia S              720 × 1280       342ppi    2                 |
| One X                 720 × 1280       312ppi    2                 |
| EVO LTE               720 × 1280       312ppi    2                 |
| Galaxy Note           800 × 1280       285ppi    2                 |
| Galaxy SIII           720 × 1280       306ppi    2                 |
| Galaxy Nexus          720 × 1280       316ppi    2                 |
| HTC Desire            480 × 800        252ppi    1.5               |
| Nexus One             480 × 800        252ppi    1.5               |
| Sensation             960 × 540        256ppi    1.5               |
| Evo 3D                960 × 540        256ppi    1.5               |
| Sensation XE          960 × 540        256ppi    1.5               |
| LG Optimus 2X         480 × 800        233ppi    1.5               |
| Defy+                 854 × 480        265ppi    1.5               |
| Milestone             480 × 854        265ppi    1.5               |
| Nexus S SAMOLED       480 × 800        235ppi    1.5               |
| Nexus S LCD           480 × 800        235ppi    1.5               |
| Galaxy S Plus         480 x 800        233ppi    1.5               |
| Galaxy SII            480 × 800        219ppi    1.5               |
| Galaxy Tab            600 × 1024       171ppi    1.5               |
| iPad mini             1024 × 768       163ppi    1                 |
| iPhone                480 × 320        163ppi    1                 |
| iPhone 3G             480 × 320        163ppi    1                 |
| iPhone 3GS            480 × 320        163ppi    1                 |
| iPad (1st gen)        1024 × 768       132ppi    1                 |
| iPad 2                1024 × 768       132ppi    1                 |
| Kidle Fire            1024 × 600       169ppi    1                 |
| Galaxy Y (S5360)      240 × 320        133ppi    0.75              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

([Sources](http://johnstejskal.com/wp/list-of-screen-resolutions-and-dpippi-for-popular-mobile-devices/))

Note that you don't need to specify or target each devices. You just follow the min-width or min-height convention to target the devices. For example if you have defined the following pages:

- **your-page.xml**
- **your-page.minW200.xml**
- **your-page.minW300.xml**

Then you're targeting **your-page.xml** below 200 dp, **your-page.minW200.xml** from minimum of 200 dp to 299 dp and **your-page.minW300.xml** from minimum of 300 dp to upwards.

Comment: This was very helpful... Thanks... :D

Comment: Glad. You got it helpful.

Comment: I just need to clarify something... if I say **your-page.minW200.xml** then does that mean I am referring to `Screen size` or `dpi` based on the table above? :)

Comment: That made me confused now... O_O

Answer (score 0):

The screen density is not an exact value, but a range。

```
ldpi(low)     <=120dpi
mdpi (medium) 120dpi~160dpi
hdpi (high)   160dpi~240dpi 
xhpdi (extra-high)) 240dpi~320dpi 
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high)) 320dpi~480dpi 
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high)) 480dpi~640dpi
```

See also:https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question.